# parse.com query throws stack overflow exception under mono

Tags: parse-platform, mono

I am building a simple C# mono application that queries data from parse.com server.

Nothing special:

```
    private static async Task<ParseGameData> DownloadGameData(DateTime dateFrom)
    {
        ParseGameData gameData = new ParseGameData();
        InitParse();

        var qHits = ParseObject.GetQuery("Hits").WhereGreaterThan("createdAt", dateFrom)
            .Limit(100).OrderBy("createdAt");
        gameData.hits = await qHits.FindAsync();

        return gameData;
    }
```

And called from another function:

```
ParseGameData gameData = DownloadGameData(timestamp).Result;
```

This works great and no exception is being thrown when querying small amount (~less than 75 records). But if I set the limit higher, application crashes and I get this:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
    System.StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult].TrySetResult (VoidResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult].TrySetFromTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, Boolean lookForOce) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult].InvokeCore (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1[System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions+VoidResult].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task completingTask) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

... and then these lines repeat.

For interest purposes: each record in database takes about ~65KB, so a 100 hits would be 6.5MB.

I've tried this code on two mono platforms, on OS X and Linux. Both platforms throw stackoverflow exceptions. However on Windows, using .NET, it works fine, even with 1000 limit. That leads me to believe it is something with mono and parse.com libraries. Any suggestions?

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it was a parse library bug. I have downgraded parse lib from 1.5.5 to 1.5.4 and now it works fine.